# converting double/floating to integer in C#

Tags: c#

My question might looks like silly, but i struck with it.
I have a string value "155.300" and i want to convert it to integer.
I tryed but throwing System.FormatException....pls someone help me out.

Comment: What's the code you're trying to use?

Comment: Actually i am getting a string value which is a decimel number as i mentioned above and i need to multiple with 1000. so that it shld be like 155300 and hv to send it to server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your source data is string you need to Convert it to `Double` first then just cast it to `int` or use `Convert.ToInt32`, but remember `Convert.ToInt32` rounds it to nearest integer number, whereas casting takes the `int` part of the number (truncate)

```
double d = Convert.ToDouble("155.00");    
int a = (int) d;
int b = Convert.ToInt32(d);
```

Or in a single Line

```
int b =(int) Convert.ToDouble("155.000");
```

**EDIT**

Since you want to use **decimal point as thousand separator**, I believe in **German culture** you can try the following.

```
int b = ((int)Convert.ToDouble("154.500", new CultureInfo("de-DE")));
```

That will give you `154500`

**EDIT 2**

Or much better is to use `int.Parse` with `NumberStyles.AllowThousands`:

```
 int b = int.Parse("154.500", NumberStyles.AllowThousands, new CultureInfo("de-DE"));
```

Comment: Hi Habib, i tried both the cases not getting correct answers. when i used first one for my value "153.500" getting 154 and whn i tried 2nd one single line sol...getting 153.

Comment: @Tim, what do you want then ? what should be the expected output ?

Comment: if original value is "154.500" then i want 154500 as int.

Comment: well, in that case, you can do a remove the decimal and try to parse it to int.

Comment: hmmm. smart idea...but let me chk.

Comment: I just posted the solution for you.

Comment: @Tim, check the edited answer, if you want to use decimal point as thousand separator, then I believe you can use German culture, check the updated answer

Comment: @Tim: Is the "." here *actually* a thousands separator, or is this actually a value of just over 153, but you want to multiply by 1000? You need to be very clear about what your data means.

Comment: actually its a frequency that some times comes as decimal value or some times int. as 154 or 154.3. watever the value i hv to multiple with 1000.

Comment: In btw i hv on more question: if i want to convert "153500" to 153.5 then wat needs to be done?? if i convert first to int and do /1000, then i am getting 153

Comment: i did, i m getting 153...but i want 153.5

Comment: @Tim, divide it with `1000d` or `1000.0` to explicitly mark it as double value and store it in double type variable

Comment: ya...i divided it with 1000.0 and stored as double...works fine. thnks once again.

Answer (score 5):

First parse it as a `decimal` or `double` (probably best to use `decimal` as you've *got* decimal data) then either cast or use something like `Math.Round`, depending on your requirements.

Basically, you need to always consider what data you've got: "155.300" isn't a string representation of an integer, so don't try to parse it as an integer. Parse it as what it is, then convert that to an integer.

Alternatively, you *could* hack at the string representation first, but personally I find that to be a more brittle approach in many cases.

EDIT: Note that if this is *really* already an integer, but with a thousands separator, you don't need to use `double` at all - you can use [`int.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yaffedz.aspx), specifying an appropriate culture and number style:

```
int parsed = int.Parse(text, NumberStyles.Integer | NumberStyles.AllowThousands,
                       culture);
```

Comment: is there a method `int.ParseExact` ? because I can't seem to find it

Comment: @Habib +1 for finding an error in the compiler generated code

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working conversion sample. Take a special look with the edge conditions,  the output may be different if using several rounding/casting techniques

```
class Program
{
    public static int MyToInt(string str)
    {
        double result;
        bool success = Double.TryParse(str, out result);
        if (!success)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(
                "Cannot parse a string into a double");
        }

        return Convert.ToInt32(result);     // 156
        //return (int)result;               // 155 <<
        //return (int)Math.Round(result);   // 156
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s = "155.500";
        int value = MyToInt(s); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
string str = "123.123";
str = str.Remove(str.IndexOf('.'), 1);
int result;
int.TryParse(str, out result);
```

**Edit**: Based on your comment, modified to multiply by thousand.
Or you can just try:

```
string str = "123.123";
double result;
double.TryParse(str, out result);

int final = (int)(result * 1000);
```